# Angular interpolation error fetching from api

Tags: angular, api, string-interpolation

This is for a project. I need to access an array from this api: https://pokeapi.co/. I am able to access the array, which looks like this:

```
{"count":1050,"next":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=20","previous":null,"results":[{"name":"bulbasaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"},{"name":"ivysaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"},{"name":"venusaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"},{"name":"charmander","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"},{"name":"charmeleon","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"},{"name":"charizard","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"},{"name":"squirtle","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"},{"name":"wartortle","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"},{"name":"blastoise","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"},{"name":"caterpie","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"},{"name":"metapod","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"},{"name":"butterfree","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/"},{"name":"weedle","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/"},{"name":"kakuna","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/"},{"name":"beedrill","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/"},{"name":"pidgey","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/"},{"name":"pidgeotto","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/"},{"name":"pidgeot","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/"},{"name":"rattata","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/"},{"name":"raticate","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/"}]}
```

I'm trying to use interpolation, to iterate the names in my template. but since 'name' is wrapped in 'results' on the api, it can only reach it if I use results in the template. This creates an error, and it often doesn't compile as a result.

my ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {PokemonData} from '../../models/pokemon';
import {PokemonService} from '../../models/services/pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon-data',
  templateUrl: './pokemon-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon-data.component.css']
})
export class PokemonDataComponent implements OnInit {
  // @Input() id: string;
  public pokemonData: PokemonData[] = [];
  private name: string;

  constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
  }
    onLoadPokemonByName(): void {
    this.pokemonService.getPokemonbyName(this.name).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(this.name);
        this.pokemonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
        console.log(this.pokemonData);
      }
    );

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onLoadPokemonByName();
  }

}
```

this is the html file

```
<p>pokemon works!</p>
<div *ngFor="let res of pokemon.results">
  <div>{{res.name}}, {{res.url}}</div>
  <button routerLink="/pokemondata/{{res.name}}">Pokemon Details</button>
</div>
```

and this is the service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Pokemon, PokemonData} from '../pokemon';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  // http call
  private baseUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';

  getPokemonList(): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
    return this.http.get<Pokemon[]>(this.baseUrl + `pokemon?limit=150`);

  }
```

my class file

```
export class Pokemon {
  // this class contains properties that contain information on Pokemons
  name: string;
  url: string;
  results: Result[];

}

export interface Result {
  results: Result[];
}
```

my question: how do I instantiate results so that i5 doesn't cause an error in the template.

additional ts file

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {PokemonService} from '../../models/services/pokemon.service';
import {PokemonData} from '../../models/pokemon';
import {Chain, Evolution, Species} from '../../models/evolution';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-evolution',
  templateUrl: './evolution.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./evolution.component.css']
})
export class EvolutionComponent implements OnInit {

evolution: Evolution;
species: Species;
chain: Chain;
private id: string;

  constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  }

   getEvolutionDetails(): void {
    this.pokemonService.getEvolutionData(this.id).subscribe((
      res => {
        console.log(this.id);
        this.evolution = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
        console.log(this.evolution);
      }
    ));

   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEvolutionDetails();
  }

}
```

html file

```
  <p *ngIf="evolution.chain.species">
  <div *ngFor="let res of evolution.chain.species">{{res.name}} </div>
```

The error I get:
Cannot read property 'chain' of undefined
and
vendor.js:77062 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'bulbasaur'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is because `pokemon` is null when you're trying to do the `*ngFor` right? In this case you can add `?` after `pokemon` in you HTML.

```
<div *ngFor="let res of pokemon?.results">
  <div>{{res.name}}, {{res.url}}</div>
  <button routerLink="/pokemondata/{{res.name}}">Pokemon Details</button>
</div>
```

And to be sure that you have result it will be better to add `?` after `res`.

```
<div *ngFor="let res of pokemon?.results">
  <div>{{res?.name}}, {{res?.url}}</div>
  <button routerLink="/pokemondata/{{res?.name}}">Pokemon Details</button>
</div>
```

Or you can just do a `if`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="pokemon">
  <div *ngFor="let res of pokemon?.results">
    <div>{{res?.name}}, {{res?.url}}</div>
    <button routerLink="/pokemondata/{{res?.name}}">Pokemon Details</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

For you second error with your `EvolutionComponent` you have 2 errors:

```
  <p *ngIf="evolution.chain.species">
  <div *ngFor="let res of evolution.chain.species">{{res.name}} </div>
```

To fix them you can do:

```
  <p *ngIf="evolution?.chain?.species">
  <div *ngFor="let res of evolution?.chain?.species | keyvalue">{{res?.value?.name}} </div>
```

The `?` is to check if the value is not null.

For the error `NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`. It's because the field species is not an array but an object so you have to use the `keyvalue` pipe. Click [here](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) for the documentation

Comment: I have a similar problem with another component. I've appended the code. Can you help me @Lud?

Comment: @HeidiE I answered you ^^

Comment: yup, everything works now. the only thing is, {{res?.value?.name}} doesn't work, but {{res?.value}} does. thanks for you help @Lud!